# Starting a loop over again c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

This code might be a bit vague, but this question is regarding an assignment I have to turn in and will be checked for plagiarism so I will just give the gist of my problem.

```
bool x = false;
while (x == false)
{
}

if (conditions)
{
    x = true;
}
while (x == true)
{
    if (a == b)
    {
        //....
    }
    else
        x = false;
}
```

I know this code might be confusing but I'll try my best to explain my problem:

Everything runs fine minus the last part. In my second while loop the condition is x == true, but if the conditions of the if statement (within the while statement) aren't satisfied, I want x == false, and I want it to go back to the first while loop for the condition x==false. However, it sets x == false, then ends the program.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wrap it all in `while(true)`

Comment: The `if(conditions)` logic seems worthless. The only way the top loop breaks is by `x == true`. I see nothing that changes it back to `false` between the top-while-loop and the bottom while-loop. You *may* get what you seek by simply doing `x = (conditions);` between the two loops and throwing out the current `if` logic.

Comment: Probably better to wrap it all in a do { ... } while (x == false);

Comment: The if(conditions) is basically a verification. If you satisfy the conditions you can move on to the next loop. However if you satisfy the else in the second while loop, x= false again, so I want to run the top while( x == false) again.

Comment: It will difficult to come up with an efficient scheme without knowing what is going on in the loops.

Comment: Thank you Richard Pennington, that worked. Can you explain why I had to do that?

Comment: You want to repeat the logic as long as x = false.

Comment: @didierc You can, but the limited algorithm posted by the OP does *not*. I concur with your comment about the difficulty in fostering anything meaningful without more info (and up ticked accordingly).

Comment: @WhozCraig. I totally agree with you. I didn't understand your point (upticked as well).

Answer (score 2):

For example you can write the following way

```
bool x = false;

do
{
    while ( x == false )
    {
        //...
    }

    if (conditions)
    {
        x = true;
    }

    while ( x == true )
    {
        if ( a == b )
        {
            //....
        }
        else
        {
            x = false;
        }
    }
} while ( x == false );
```

Only there is a logical error in your code because you will get an infinite loop as result of the last assignment false to x. That is either the second while loop will be infinite if x will not be assigned false or external do while loop will be infinite if x will be assigned false.:) So you need to add some other condition in this schema. For example there could be one more assignment of x.

```
bool x = false;

do
{
    while ( x == false )
    {
        //...
    }

    if (conditions)
    {
        x = true;
    }

    while ( x == true )
    {
        if ( a == b )
        {
            //....
        }
        else
        {
            x = false;
        }
    }

    if ( one_more_condition ) x = true;
} while ( x == false );
```

Or you could use a break statement somewhere within the external do-while loop or the internal second while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an else block and use `goto` to go back: put `firstloop:` before `while (x == false)` then `goto firstloop;` after `x = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another loop around both loops. Based on your description, I think you could do it with another `while (x==false)` loop. E.g.,

```
bool x = false;
while (x==false)
{
 while (x == false)
 {...}
 ...
 while (x == true)
 {...}
}
```

But I would probably do it like this for clarity:

```
bool x = false;
bool allDone = false;
while (allDone==false)
{
 while (x == false)
 {...}
 ...
 while (x == true)
 {...
   if (conditions)
     allDone = true;
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
        bool x = false;
        CheckCondition:
        while (x == false)
        {
        }

        if (conditions)
        {
            x = true;
        }
        while (x == true)
        {
            if (a == b)
            {
                //....
            }
            else
            {   
                x = false;
                goto CheckCondition;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Though it is the easiest solution, but its not wise to use goto statement here.

Answer (score 0):

Move both of your while loops to another while loop with condition x==false so that your code looks like the one below:-

```
bool x = false;
while(x==false)
   {
       while (x == false)
       {
       }

       if (conditions)
       {
          x = true;
       }
       while (x == true)
       {
          if (a == b)
          {
          //....
          }
          else
          x = false;
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a while statement that breaks when you want it to. The bottom while will break and then the whole thing will go back to the top.

Also, your if statement is logically redundant. The top while statement will break when x != false (therefore true).

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use like this :

```
        bool x = false;
        while (x == false)
        {
        }

        if (conditions)
        {
            x = true;
        }
        while (x == true)
        {
            if (a == b)
            {
                //....
            }
            else
            {   
                x = false;
                while (x == false)
                {
                }

                if (conditions)
                {
                    x = true;
                }
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure might work, depending on the details of what you are doing

```
while (true) {
    for( bool x = false; x == false; ) {
        // do stuff... set x to true at some point
    }

    if (! conditions) break; // Done if conditions aren't met

    while (a == b)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```